# Wasserstein distance of convolution of measures

Tags: probability-theory, metric-spaces, optimal-transport, wasserstein

Let $\mu_1, \mu_2,\nu_1,\nu_2$ be measures on $\mathbb{R}^d$. It is well known that the $p$-Wasserstein distance satisfies
$$\mathcal{W}_p(\nu_1 *\mu_1, \nu_1 *\mu_2) = \mathcal{W}_p(\mu_1,\mu_2),$$
by considering the coupling formulation. I am wondering whether this result can be extended and whether one can say
$$\mathcal{W}_p(\nu_1 *\mu_1, \nu_2 *\mu_2) \leq \mathcal{W}_p(\nu_1,\nu_2) + \mathcal{W}_p(\mu_1,\mu_2).$$
Taking $\nu_1=\nu_2$ gives us the original expression, so this is a proper generalization. Is this in fact true? I have had some trouble proving it using the coupling formulation, so either a proof or counterexample is of interest to me.

Comment: Provided you first statement is correct, the second should follow immediately by triangle inequality.

Comment: Ah, of course! If you add that as an answer I will accept it.